# particular solution of a difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, signal-processing

I am unable to find a particular solution of the following difference equation
$$
y[k-1]-5y[k]+6y[k+1]=-u[k-1]+4u[k]
$$
with $u[k]=\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^k$.

This is what I tried so far. Because $u[k]=\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^k$ we try $y_p[k]=\alpha \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^k$. Substituting this is in the difference equation gives us
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{k-1}-5\alpha \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^k + 6\alpha \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{k+1} &= -\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{k-1} + 4 \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^k\\
\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{k-1}\bigg(\alpha -\frac{5\alpha}{2}+\frac{6\alpha}{4}\bigg)&= \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{k-1}
\end{align}
$$
Thus $\Big(\alpha -\frac{5\alpha}{2}+\frac{6\alpha}{4}\Big)=1$ which results in $0\alpha=2$ which has no possible solution.

The problem is that I have no idea which particular solution I could try that solves this problem, namely the fact that $1-5/2+6/4=0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your recurrence is linear.  try setting it to one term of your sum, then the other.

Comment: Do you mean first solving for $-u[k-1]$ and then for $4u[k]$? Because that gives exactly the same problem.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  The solutions posted below show how to handle cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We change notation slightly. Note that $-u_{k-1}+4u_k=\frac{4}{2^k}-\frac{2}{2^k}=\frac{2}{2^k}$. We look for a solution of the shape $y_i=\alpha\frac{i}{2^i}$.

Substitute in $6y_{k+1}-5y_k+y_{k-1}$,  forgetting about the $\alpha$ for a while. We get
$$\frac{6(k+1)}{2^{k+1}}-\frac{5k}{2^k}+\frac{k-1}{2^{k-1}}.$$
This simplifies to 
$$\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\left(6k+6 -10k+4k+4k-4\right).$$
I am sure you can finish from here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question though, why do you pick $y_i=\alpha\frac{i}{2^i}$ and not $y_i=\alpha\frac{1}{2^i}$ as I would have done?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial  of the recurrence is $6x^2-5x+1$, which has roots $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$. Your right-hand side is of the shape $\frac{b}{2^k}$, so a constant times the $k$-th power of a root of the characteristic polynomial. In that case, a standard trick is the one I used, because the procedure you used then *always* leads to trouble. A similar trick is used with linear differential equations. If the right-hand side had been say $\frac{b}{5^k}$ then your method would have worked.

Comment: Thank you! I'll remember the trick.

Comment: You are welcome. A related trick is used in **homogeneous** (say second order) equations, in which that characteristic polynomial has a double root $r$. Then the general solution has shape $y_n=Ar^n +Bnr^n$.

Comment: That one I knew. It is similar to differential equations. But that first trick that solved my problem is new for me. Again, thank you very much for your help. I got really stuck with this one.

Answer (score 0):

When $y[k] = c \lambda^k$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $L(y) = 0$, you should look for a particular solution of $L(y) = a \lambda^k$ of the form $y[k] = c k \lambda^k$.

Comment: My solution of the homogeneous equation is $y_h[k]=Ae^{1/2k}+Be^{1/3k}$. Trying $y_p[k]=Ace^{1/2k}$ however gives me no solution (and comes nowhere near to the solution I found based on the answer from André). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: No, the solutions of the homogeneous equation are $y_h[k] = A (1/2)^k + B (1/3)^k$.  For the particular solution you want $y_p[k] = c k (1/2)^k$.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I don't know why I picked $y_h[k]=Ae^{1/2k}+Be^{1/3k}$. Then your answer also solves the problem. Thanks.